# Can I use a type bound on a Scala abstract method and then "tighten up" the definition in a subclass?

Tags: scala, types

Essentially I want to do something like this:

```
class Shape

class CoordSystem
class C3D(val x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) extends CoordSystem
class C2D(val x: Double, y: Double) extends CoordSystem

abstract class Shape {
  def getCoords[C <: CoordSystem]: List[C]
} 

class Pyramid extends Shape {
  def getCoords: List[C3D] = 
    List(new C3D(1,2,1), new C3D(1,1,1), new C3D(2,2,1), new C3D(2,1,1), new C3D(1.5,1.5,3))
}   
>> error: class Pyramid needs to be abstract, since method getCoords in class Shape of type [C <: CoordSystem]List[C] is not defined
```

I've seen a handful of different ideas on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025207/scala-how-can-i-implement-a-clone-method-on-a-superclass-and-use-it-in-a-subcla), but none of them seem quite right for this case - because they don't seem to let me write code elsewhere which refers to `myShape.getCoords` as if it's been correctly defined in a `Shape` subclass, returning a List of objects from a subclass of `CoordSystem`.

I also found [an interesting discussion about generics](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Surprising-type-mismatch-with-generics-td2257197.html) on the Scala Lang email list, but couldn't quite tie it back to my situation.

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class CoordSystem
class C3D(val x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) extends CoordSystem
class C2D(val x: Double, y: Double) extends CoordSystem

trait ShapeLike[+C <: CoordSystem] {
  def getCoords: List[C]
}

abstract class Shape extends ShapeLike[CoordSystem]

class Pyramid extends Shape with ShapeLike[C3D] {
  def getCoords: List[C3D] =
    List(new C3D(1, 2, 1), new C3D(1, 1, 1), new C3D(2, 2, 1), new C3D(2, 1, 1), new C3D(1.5, 1.5, 3))
}
```

Of course, nothing forces you to declare the extra type `ShapeLike` to do this; its purpose is to allow you to use the type `Shape` without annoying extra type parameters.

So, actually the answer to your question as stated in the title is: you may “tighten up” the  type bound of a type parameter in a subclass if it is defined as a covariant type parameter in the superclass; conversely, you may “loosen” the type bound of a contravariant type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

A type parameter is a type parameter, and the super class contract demands that you do not tighten its contract -- making it less strict would not violate the contract, though I don't think it is allowed.

You can do something else, however: put the type inside the class.

```
class Shape

class CoordSystem
class C3D(val x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) extends CoordSystem
class C2D(val x: Double, y: Double) extends CoordSystem

abstract class Shape {
  type C <: CoordSystem
  def getCoords: List[C]
} 

class Pyramid extends Shape {
  override type C = C3D
  def getCoords: List[C3D] = 
    List(new C3D(1,2,1), new C3D(1,1,1), new C3D(2,2,1), new C3D(2,1,1), new C3D(1.5,1.5,3))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I thought about this approach (having seen it in the other post). But I couldn't figure out how to make it play nicely with separate classes using Shape and CoordSystem type parameters. With Jean-Philippe's approach I was able to write e.g. `Class Blah[C <: CoordSystem, S <: Shape with ShapeLike[CS]` and then use `getCoords` to return a `List[C]` within a Blah method. I couldn't figure out the equivalent syntax with type overriding "internal" to the class. Does my comment make sense?